# for each loop in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, foreach

How to implement *foreach* in Groovy?
I have an example of code in Java, but I don't know how to implement this code in Groovy...

Java:

```
for (Object objKey : tmpHM.keySet()) {
   HashMap objHM = (HashMap) list.get(objKey);
}
```

I read http://groovy.codehaus.org/Looping, and tried to translate my Java code to Groovy, but it's not working.

```
for (objKey in tmpHM.keySet()) {
   HashMap objHM = (HashMap) list.get(objKey);
}
```

Comment: General note: you will get a lot better answers if you say specifically *what* does not work (no "it's not working"). I just tried, and the loop works.

Comment: A lot of example using loop in grooy here: http://grails.asia/groovy-each-examples

Answer (score 114, accepted):

as simple as:

```
tmpHM.each{ key, value -> 
  doSomethingWithKeyAndValue key, value
}
```

Comment: Using a closure isn't always the best solution.  the .each() approach doesn't allow for break;

Comment: this is exactly how the `each` and all other groovy collection methods are built: they just blindnly iterate through one be one. If you need another iteration logic, you must stick with traditional loops

Comment: `tmpHM.eachWithIndex{ key, value -> 
  doSomethingWithKeyAndValue()
}
`

Comment: @injecteer:  you can break if you use `find` and return true.

Comment: @BobStine it's not really a break. `find` and `each` have totally different purposes

Comment: @injecteer your point eludes me. 

I stand by my statement: the "find" method can be used if you wish to conditionally stop iterating through a collection (aka "break").

Comment: That worked brilliant for my List!

Answer (score 85):

This one worked for me:

```
def list = [1,2,3,4]
for(item in list){
    println item
}
```

Source: [Wikia](http://code.wikia.com/wiki/Groovy).

Answer (score 10):

You can use the below groovy code for maps with for-each loop.

```
def map=[key1:'value1', key2:'value2']

for (item in map) {
  log.info item.value // this will print value1 value2
  log.info item       // this will print key1=value1 key2=value2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine.

```
def list = [["c":"d"], ["e":"f"], ["g":"h"]]
Map tmpHM = [1:"second (e:f)", 0:"first (c:d)", 2:"third (g:h)"]

for (objKey in tmpHM.keySet()) {   
    HashMap objHM = (HashMap) list.get(objKey);
    print("objHM: ${objHM}  , ")
}
```

prints `objHM: [e:f]  , objHM: [c:d]  , objHM: [g:h]  ,`

See https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5135817529884672

Then click "edit in console", "execute script"